# Understanding and using user provided file structure

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-engine

I have at my disposal a folder with data provided to me by a person that knows nothing about GIS. I have the impression that its file structure was generated by some esri desktop product. I have only ArcGIS Engine license, so no desktop product for me to check the data.
The folder structure goes like this:

```
ROOTFOLDER
--DTED1
----file1.img
----file1.rrd
--DTED2
--info
----arc.dir
----arc0000.dat
----arc0000.nit
----arc0001.dat
----<many other files>
--RASTER_DATA
----GEOTIFF
------file2.aux
------file2.rrd
------file2.tfw
------file2.tiff
```

Is this a form of geodatabase?

What program understands this folder structure?

How can I use it?

Should I convert this *programmatically* to some form of other geodatabase (file or personal) and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see what sorts of datasets are stored in a particular folder, you can use the [IWorkspaceFactory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IWorkspaceFactory_Interface/002500000m9w000000/) interface.  Make a list of concrete workspacefactory classes (rasterworkspacefactory, arcinfoworkspacefactory etc.) using the activator, as outlined [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/c778d2bb-eb36-4793-9c89-20795811c5eb.htm#WkspFac).

For each workspacefactory in the list, see if IWorkspaceFactory.IsWorkspace is true for the folder. If so, call [IWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenFromFile_Method/002500000mnn000000/) to return an IWorkspace.  You may then iterate through the top level datasets using IWorkspace.DatasetNames, and the subsets using IDataset.Subsets.  For performance it is faster to loop through IDatasetNames.  This would allow you to build a treeview where each node in the tree represents an IDatasetName, and do [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) to open the dataset when user expands the node, via IName.Open.

Answer (score 1):

The tfw is a world file, and is the georeference data for the tiff, for ArcView.

rrd is an ERDAS Imagine file and the img file is associated with it.

Under DTED2 is ArcView data stuff.